# Identity platform auth blocking function deploy in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-identity, google-identity-toolkit

I am trying to write an auth blocking function to prevent users creating accounts from the client side in google identity platform. I have written it in typescript but I am struggling to deploy it

Here is a the website about the blocking functions https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/blocking-functions

My actual function looks like this

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as gcipCloudFunctions from 'gcip-cloud-functions';
const authClient = new gcipCloudFunctions.Auth();


exports.beforeCreateBlockingFunction = authClient.functions().beforeCreateHandler((user, context) => {
    throw new gcipCloudFunctions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', `Unauthorized email "${user.email}"`);
});
```

1. Have I got the method signature correct?
2. I am trying to deploy it using the following command. I am not sure whether this works with typescript. Is this the correct way?

```
// Http trigger with Cloud Functions.
// gcloud functions deploy beforeCreateBlockingFunction --runtime nodejs10 --region europe-west1 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated
```

Any help is appreciated.
Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaration of method for typescript is not correct.. name of function don't have to be beforeCreate.. you can name it as per your convention. Refer below TS code for beforeCreateHandler event

```
import * as gcipCloudFunctions from 'gcip-cloud-functions';
const authClient = new gcipCloudFunctions.Auth();

export const beforeRegister = authClient.functions().beforeCreateHandler((user: gcipCloudFunctions.UserRecord, 
          context: gcipCloudFunctions.AuthEventContext) => {
  console.log("User Object: " + JSON.stringify(user));
  console.log("Context Object: " + JSON.stringify(context));
  
  return {
    customClaims: {
      verified: true
    },      
  };
});
```

Comment: I get this this (also ran tsc in the /functions folder beforehand): 

ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: lib/index.js does not exist; Error ID: bc73f5cd

Comment: most likely you are giving your deploy command with flag --source=./lib; which expects your compiled js files in lib folder. Make sure your ts files are getting compiled under lib folder; also make sure your package.json nd package-lock.json are copied along with compiled files in lib as thats the folder which will be referred for deployment.

Comment: Got it working... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I’m not really sure if this is how you are deploying your code, but I want to underline that you may be changing the name of the `beforeCreate` function to `beforeCreateBlockingFunction`.  I thought you could choose any name you like for the function, but I realized the name should be as the documentation you are following says.